ASP.NET Core : request logging of unauthorized requests
ASP.NET Core is offering two options for request logging

HTTP logging
W3C Logging

However, neither of them seem to log requests that are unauthorized (HTTP response code 401).
Is there a way to get any of them to also log unauthorized requests?

ASP.NET Core: Configuring Request Logging for Unauthorized Requests - essentially, use a custom MiddleWare

I tested a method return Unauthorized(); with using httplogging and it actually get logged.
